# Proving the independence of random indicator variables when deriving the binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Short question: Is independence of random indicator variables a necessary *assumption* to derive the Binomial distribution ?

But far as I can see, using the Definition (that is at the same time a theorem) from below, taken from Snells probability book, page 144,  we can do without this assumption and *prove* that the  random indicator variables are independent! (as opposed to, for example, the geometric distribution, were we need independence to derive it).

EDIT: A better explanation: Do we in the text below *assume* the variables are independent, or to we *deduce* it from their definition ?
To me it seems the latter is the case, since we *concretely* define the $X_j$ on a *given sample space*, so we can use the definition of independence of variables to test if they are indeed independent or not - so independence is *proven*, not assumed.

---

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can prove that the $X_j$ are independent from the definition.

Comment: [Déjà vu](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/267238).

Comment: @did not really. See the comments below your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The text you reproduce *assumes* from the start that the random variables are independent hence, as noted in the comments, the question seems moot. However:

> The sum of non independent Bernoulli random variables can have a binomial distribution.

For an example, let $p$ in $(0,1)$, $q=1-p$, and $(X,Y)$ with values in $\{0,1\}^2$ with
$$
\mathbb P(X=Y=0)=q^2,\qquad\mathbb P(X=Y=1)=p^2,
$$
and
$$
\mathbb P(X=0,Y=1)=(1+\theta)pq,\qquad\mathbb P(X=1,Y=0)=(1-\theta)pq,
$$
for some $|\theta|\leqslant1$. Then $X+Y$ is binomial $(2,p)$ but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent except when $\theta=0$. To wit, the distribution of $X$ is
$$
\mathbb P(X=0)=q(1+\theta p),\qquad\mathbb P(X=1)=p(1-\theta q),
$$
and the distribution of $Y$ is
$$
\mathbb P(X=0)=q(1-\theta p),\qquad\mathbb P(Y=1)=p(1+\theta q),
$$
hence, for example,
$$
\mathbb P(X=Y=1)=p^2\ne p^2(1-\theta^2q^2)=\mathbb P(X=1)\mathbb P(Y=1).
$$

Comment: In the "deja-vu" question of mine, I asked at 4), which was the most important to me, if it is trivial that these variables are independent or not - since it seemed odd to me that no sketch of a proof was in the text - and I mentioned I *proved* that they were independent. Your answer indicated, since you mentioned one had to use pen and paper to verify the independence, that a proof was indeed required. But now you're saying that a proof actually isn't required, since the variables are already assumed to be independent. What is true now ?

Comment: (Jonathan Christensen comment (not "comments") seems to imply that the independence of variables is not an *assumption*, but rather a *conclusion* one can draw from the definition of those variable, which, in my view, requires a *proof*.)

Comment: Let me try once again: the book defines the distribution as a product measure. Hence, by definition of independence, the random variables are independent. Nothing to prove (except, if you insist, that $m(A_1\times\cdots\times A_n)=m(A_1)\cdots m(A_n)$ as soon as $m(\omega)=m(\omega_1)\cdots m(\omega_n)$--hence my (probably too generous) mention of pen and paper).

Comment: exactly! Only that proving $m(A_1 \times \cdots A_n)=m(A_1)\cdots m(A_n)$ (at least to me) doesn't seem to be that trivial, since the proof goes $$m(A_1 \times \cdots \times A_n)=m(\bigcup_{(\omega_1\ldots,\omega_n) } \{(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n)\}=$$ $$ =\sum_{(\omega_1\ldots,\omega_n)} m(\{(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_n)\}) =\sum_{(\omega_1\ldots,\omega_n)} m(\omega_1)\cdots m(\omega_n)=m(A_1)\cdots m(A_n).$$ Or do you know an easier proof ?

Comment: No I do not. But what is difficult in the proof you delineate? Sum of products of nonnegative terms = product of the sums, *et voilà!*